# UART-USB Bridge

Tags: bridge

Take the CP2102N for example. This chip is mainly a UART-USB bridge, but it also has a voltage regulator with it. Now to my question, can I use both bridge and regulator functionalities and hope that both function optimally? I am just worried that if I don't use a separate regulator, then the one supplied by the chip will not be as efficient.

Comment: For what purpose you intend to use the built-in regulator of USB-UART bridge chips? Are you asking if it can be used to power other chips as well, or are you asking if it is better to use an external regulator? And in which case, bus-powered or self-powered USB device? Using which voltages? Please can you make the question more clear what kind of answer you are after.

Comment: I'm using it as a input voltage for a ESP32-PICO-D4. The input voltage required is 3.3V, and I wanted to use an external regulator, but I see that the device has a regulator itself. I want it to interface with a USB. It looks like this: USB --> USB-UART bridge --> voltage regulator. I planned on omitting the voltage regulator since the bridge already has one but was just wondering if this is the best approach

Comment: You are asking the wrong thing then. You have a specific case of chip with regulator needing to power a specific module, and it has a specific answer, which is different than a general answer.

Comment: In general, a (non-power) chip's built-in regulator is meant to power itself, this way, a simple one-chip PCB can save a component. However, if it's a larger design, it's not a good idea to use a chip's built-in DC/DC or linear regulator to power anything else. It's not worth saving a $0.5 regulator at the expense of this much design uncertainty.  Sometimes it's not even appropriate to connect the output to a global supply rail. However, sometimes the margin is enough to allow you to get away with it. Check the *Electrical Characteristics* and make the decision yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The CP2102 uses a linear regulator. It's efficiency will be almost the same as any other LDO you would use (with the difference due to the bias current that is usually quite low). If you are consuming significant current, it won't be very efficient but at lower current, it can be better then switch mode power supply (SMPS).

So, yes, you can use the one integrated!

Comment: I highly doubt it has exactly same efficiency as any other regulator, mainly because different linear regulators also won't have equal efficency. They all consume different amounts of power to provide the same output.

Comment: I imagine you are talking about the quiescent current. If so, you are right, it will impact efficiency. But, in USB powered application, 90uA will be most likely negligible.

Answer (score 0):

What you really wanted to know does not match the question you asked. This is not about efficiency or powering things in general. In general regulators on USB chipsets can provide current to power other chips, but you can't draw more current than what the regulator can provide of course.

The answer is you can't use CP2102N built-in regulator to power an ESP32-Pico-D4 module.

The CP2102 regulator is rated for 100mA max output, with the chip consuming about 15mA, leaving you max 85mA for other purposes.

The ESP32-Pico-D4 requires 80mA **on average**, meaning it requires more that 80mA in bursts and less when idle. The datasheet states a minimum requirement of 500mA, which the CP2102N regulator can't provide you.

Comment: I see, thank you big bro!